# how to style nav lists menu using Bootstrap css

Tags: css, list, menu, styles, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm using a bootstrap menu with two level list (drop down menu). Example of code I’m using is:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">                  
                                                          
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Item0<span> class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#Item1">Item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Item2">Item2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Item3">Item3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Item4">Item4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Item5">Item5</a></li>

    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                   <li><a href="#Item1">Item13</a></li>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#Item1">Item131</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Item2">Item132</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Item3">Item133</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Item4">Item134</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Item5">Item135</a></li>

    </ul>
                   <li><a href="#Item2">Item23</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#Item3">Item33</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I would like to make some modyfications in colours. However, when I made a change in following class:

```
.navbar-default .nav li a{
 ...
 }
```

it changes colour of all list elements.
Is it possible to style nested lists in using different colour while level up list has a different one?

e.g. "Item0, Item13 Item23 Item33" in red, "Item1 .. Item5" in blue and so on...

How to get it works using a Bootstrap or shall I create a custom css?

Answer (score 1):

you can style a specific group of elements by adding a class:

```
<li class="yourclass"><a href="#Item1">Item1</a></li>
```

and then use CSS to style all the elements has the same class:

```
.yourclass { color: red }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesnt overrides bootstrap :(

Answer (score 0):

Sure: add a class to elements you want to color differently and style background there. Example

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#Item1" class='red'>Item131</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Item2" class='red'>Item132</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Item3" class='blue'>Item133</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Item4">Item134</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Item5">Item135</a></li>

</ul>
```

And css

```
.red {
...
}
.blue {
...
}
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can give additional class to the specific list items to overwrite the default design in booststrap.

for example :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#Item1" class="custom">Item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Item2">Item2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Item3" class="custom">Item3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Item4">Item4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Item5" class="custom">Item5</a></li>

</ul>
```

then in a new css file overwrite the default custom design.

```
.custom{
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying acc to waht you sugest but adding a class and styling dosn't work.

e.g.

```
    .red {
    color:red;
    }
```

but

```
    .red {
     color:red !important; 
    }
```

start to works - can you explain me why???

Comment: What is !important?
The !important rule in CSS is used to add more importance to a property/value than normal.

In fact, if you use the !important rule, it will override ALL previous styling rules for that specific property on that element!